# HotSpot connectin Issue in Android 5.0 and above

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, wifimanager, wifi, hotspot

I am trying to Connect Wifi and HotSpot programmatically.
I have referred the https://github.com/nickrussler/Android-Wifi-Hotspot-Manager-Class from it.
It is working fine till the Android 4.4 version. But it is not working from Android 5.0 and above versions. I have not seen anything related to wifi and Hotspot changes in the docs also. How to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the following permissions in the manifest file working fine in Android 5.0 and above versions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```